# How to color item text in GridView for non-selected lines only?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView with image buttons for selecting rows.  I am using an OnRowDataBound event to color selected rows Blue:

```
e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
```

Now that works great as long as I don't set a color either in the CSS stylesheet or on the grid Items themselves.  If I do that, then all rows are colored that color and I don't get my Blue selected rows color for selected rows.  I would like to color the text in the grid something other than black.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is just to have ASP.NET write the style to each cell in the row so that it overrides any CSS at the row level. Try...

```
foreach(TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
{
  cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```